Lookup value across multiple tabs, if lookup value meets criteria then return tab name
I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs, with new tabs added on occasion. Each tab has unique IDs in one column, dates across the top, and % values under the date, between 0% and 100%. Not all tabs have the same subset of unique IDs, but some IDs will appear across multiple tabs.
In one master tab, with all IDs, I need to be able to lookup the % value for each ID and date, then return the name of the tab if the value returned is > 0%.
I have an existing formula that sums the % across each tab and returns the total, which works. I've tried reverse-engineering this formula to say IF the value returned from each tab is > 0, then return tab name, and so far I'm having no luck.
The formula that's working for summing the % across each tab is:
=LET(
    x, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(B$1,$B$1:$G$1,0),4),"1",""),
    SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&Tab_List&"'!"&x&"$1:"&x&"$1000"), INDIRECT("'"&Tab_List&"'!a$1:a$1000"),$A2))
)

Where:

Tab_List is a named range of all the tab names in the file
B$1 is the month

The formula I've tried to use to return the tab names where there is an ID match and the % for that month is > 0 is:
=LET(
    col, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(B$15,$B$1:$G$1,0), 4), "1", ""),
    tabindx, ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & COUNTA(Tab_List))),
    found, IF(SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT("'" & Tab_List  & "'!" & col & "$1:" & col & "$1000")>0)*(INDIRECT("'"&Tab_List&"'!B$1:B$1000")=$A15))>0, Tab_List, ""),
    TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER(found, found <> ""))
)

The above formula returns a #VALUE! error.
The master sheet is a similar structure to the below:
Master data tab - all IDs and months
Each individual tab is similar to the below, with varying IDs and % under each month:
Individual tab - selected IDs

Try something like this:
=Let(x, SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(B$1,$B$1:$G$1,0),4),"1",""),
    ToCol(
        ByRow(Tab_List,
            Lambda(tab, 
                If(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&tab&"'!"&x&"$1:"&x&"$1000"), INDIRECT("'"&tab&"'!a$1:a$1000"),$A2)>0,
                    tab,
                    NA()
                )
            )
        )
    , 3)
)

It uses a ByRow to evaluate each tab in your Tab_List one by one, run the SumIfs for that sheet, and then return either the tab name (if the result was >0), or an #N/A error (if the result was <=0)
Then it uses a ToCol to remove all of the #N/A, which will leave you with a list of all the Tabs that contain the value.
If you need the result in a single cell, rather than a column of tabs, then wrap it all in a TEXTJOIN
